# 500 (Internal Server Error) asp mvc

Tags: server, internal

When I am running my code I got an error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

I am using two tables one is Order and OrderDetails, there are a relationship between them.

**This is my index javascript code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ordenTrabajo").DataTable({
 "ajax": {
 "url": "/Home/GetData",
 "type": "GET",
 "datatype": "json"
},
 "columns": [
     { "data": "OrderID" },
     { "data": "OT" },
     { "data": "Cliente" },
     { "data": "Tipo" },
     { "data": "NumParte" },
     { "data": "FechaIni" },
     { "data": "FechaFin" },
    ]
 });
 });
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
```

**This is my Control code:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
public JsonResult GetData()
{
 InselDBEntities1 dc = new InselDBEntities1();
 List<Order> orderList = dc.Orders.ToList();
 return Json(orderList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

Image with more details.

[Image detais](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SPBdSNOAiwAHwtSUEvTFExJCczQdrj6Q)

Please help me out!!!
Thanks.

Comment: It would appear that `dc.Orders` doesn't exist, causing an unhandled access violation when you try to call it's `ToList()` method. Debug your code to find out why it's failing. Also, your image links are invalid. Upload them using the *Image* button on the toolbar so that they are placed in the SO location at imgur instead, so they'll be preserved along with your question. Posting them on your OneDrive account does not ensure they stay available here, and if they're not in your post you shouldn't be adding them.

Comment: thanks for your coments look the image https://i.imgur.com/N5cseQl.png https://i.imgur.com/u4xDjkr.png https://i.imgur.com/8yA5zxg.png